# Next.js static export, routes, dynamic routes and .htaccess

Tags: reactjs, .htaccess, next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing

TDLR;

### Any idea what would be the best way to achieve successful reload of dynamic routing in a static export of a next.js app (`next build && next export`) without `getStaticPaths` ?

When I was working with create-react-app and react-router, I **had** to add the following `.htaccess` file in the `/public` folder which would be copied/pasted int he output `/build` folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

It allows for any page reload from any route to be redirected to the correct route within the app, instead of having a 404.

With Next.js, ***as a static site connected to an external api***, it seems a bit more complicated to have that kind of behaviour with dynamic routes.
It's not dynamic routes that I can generate with `getStaticPaths` because I can't anticipate those paths.

My page is a quizz where you can see your results and share them if you wish.
So that I have

- a page `/result` which are my private results, when I'm logged in
- a page `/result/[anyName]` which would be the public results

It's been very hard to make the page reload working properly, without a 403 or 404.
I've tried a lot of stuff, like

- adding a RewriteRule in . `RewriteRule ^result/(.*)$ /result [R=301,NC,L]` -> didn't work
- adding an `exportPathMap` in my `next.config.js` -> didn't work.

```js
const moduleExports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  exportPathMap: () => ({
    "/": { page: "/" },
    "/result/arnaud": { page: "/result" },
  }),
  images: {
    loader: "imgix",
    path: "",
  },
  trailingSlash: true,
};
```

What I ended up doing is a trick : in the `index.js` at the root of my pages, the one showing for the path `/`:

```js
const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (router.asPath?.includes("result") && router.asPath?.split("/").length > 1) {
      router.push(router.asPath);
    }
  }, [router.asPath]);
```

It's actually doing the trick, but I don't like that so much. It was much easier with a reliable `.htaccess` that I could blindly copy paste from projects to projects.

Anything better ?

Answer (score 0):

I think best way for **normal routes** is:

> Open `next.config.js` and add the `trailingSlash` config:
>
> ```
> module.exports = {
>   trailingSlash: true,
> }
> ```

More info: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/trailingSlash

For **dynamic routes** should to add a `.htaccess` file for every dynamic routes. for example:

Suppose this is the structure of a dynamic route after build:

```
product/[pid]/index.html
```

Add a `.htaccess` file in `product` folder like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) /product/[pid]/index.html [NC,L]
```